# How to get videos by channel using youtube_it gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube-api

How can I use youtube_it gem for Ruby on Rails to get videos from youtube channel (https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCwHnsUEYrQUTUxC4dvrv0QQ)?

Or can you advise me an another gem that can help me?

Answer (score 1):

this is how I do it.

I have this in my config/initializers/youtube_it.rb:

```
$youtube_it = YouTubeIt::Client.new(dev_key: ENV['YOUTUBE_KEY'])
```

Get the first page of videos:

```
    query = {
      author: channel_url.split('/').last,
      order_by: 'published',
      page: 1,
    }

    # scraping from newesr to oldest
    videos = $youtube_it.videos_by(query).videos
```

And here is a scraping example, where you'd schedule a job to call the scrape method periodically.

The method first scrapes from newest videos to oldest. Then the `backward_scrape_done` is set to `true` and then scrapes only new videos.

```
class Import < ActiveRecord::Base

  def scrape
    query = {
      author: channel_url.split('/').last,
      order_by: 'published',
    }

    query[:page] = cursor

    # scraping from newesr to oldest
    videos = fetch_videos(query)


    if videos.count == 0
      # we've reached the end
      self.backward_scrape_done = true
      self.cursor = 0
    end

    for video in videos
      add_video video
    end

    # next time scrape next page
    self.cursor = cursor + 1

  ensure
    self.scraped_at = Time.now
    self.save!
  end

  def fetch_videos(query)
    $youtube_it.videos_by(query).videos
  end


  def add_video video
    url = video.player_url.
      gsub(/[?&]feature=youtube_gdata_player/, '')

    # skip this video if its already there
    if Video.where(youtube_url: url).first
      self.cursor = 0
      save
      return
    end

    video = YoutubeVideo.create!(
      title: video.title,
      duration: video.duration,
      description: video.description,
      youtube_url: url,
    )
  end
end
```

Hope that helps!

Update: As youtube is getting rid of its API V2 soon, you should switch to something that supports the latest API, like the `yt` gem I use now:

https://github.com/Fullscreen/yt